# There was this animated show with weird animation style with kids fighting monsters

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I genuinely can't remember the name of it but basically I remember it aired in the early 2000s it had this weird animation style and a specific scene I remember is where these kids had like an agency maybe? Where they helped others who were being affected by the monsters, one of the kids kept having bad dreams about a monster and couldn't sleep so they helped them out somehow. There was also a train scene during this and all I remember is this show creeped me out.

Comment: What was weird about the animation style?

Comment: It was really...idk funky a lot of harsh lines and their body parts were exaggerated. I think?